# Neutrinos at the OPERA experiment

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, mass, neutrinos

The probability that a neutrino oscillates from a species $a$ to a species $b$ is given by

\begin{equation}
P(a \to b) = \sin^2 (2 \theta_{ab}) \sin^2 \left( 1.27 \frac{\Delta m^2 L}{E_\nu} \right)
\end{equation}

Which means that the minimum distance $L$ that maximizes neutrino oscillation is

\begin{equation}
L = \frac{E_\nu}{1.27 \Delta m^2 (\pi/2)}
\end{equation}

For a neutrino beam with energy $E_\nu$, the distance at which the detector should be placed is $L$, where the probability that the neutrino changed flavour is maximum.

Here's what I don't understand - the experiment OPERA, which operated under $E_\nu = 17 \, GeV$, has $L \approx 8500$ km, considering oscillations $\nu_\mu \to \nu_\tau$. But, of course, the detector was at a much smaller distance to the beam than this, at 730 km. Why this distance with this beam energy, then? The T2K experiment, for instance, has $L \approx 300$ km, and the distance between the beam and the detector was 295 km. These distances are close to each other, but that doesn't happen for the OPERA experiment.

Comment: It was probably a compromise so as not to have to build a neutrino detector further away than the radius of the Earth.

Comment: Why not lower the energy, then? 17 GeV is quite above tau production, which has a mass around 1.8 GeV. For a lower energy, the distance for which the probability is maximum would also be lower. I don't see the reason for working with 17 GeV...

Comment: The experiment's sensitivity to anomalous CP violation is a function of neutrino energy, so it might be because of that.

Comment: *"17 GeV is quite above tau production"* That would be true in center of momentum kinematics, but this is fixed target kinematics. Many people are surprised by how much higher (than the mass of the desired product) [the threshold energy for fixed target kinematics can be](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10602/calculating-threshold-energy-of-particle-reactions). (This is the fundamental 'Why?" of bothering with expensive and difficult colliders in the first place.)